# iOS Remote.app URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url, remote.app

I've discovered that Apple's Remote.app on iOS has a URL scheme. Opening `remote://` opens the app. Does anyone know of any other ways to, say, open a certain playlist/shared library via this URL scheme? Or is it just for opening the app?

Answer (score -2):

You can use URL Schemes to not only open an app but you can use it to open a playlist. [example](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/musiconizer-albums-for-your/id441907472?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

Comment: Does this app work with Apple's Remote app? Or the local Music player app? Or something else entirely?